# Highlight NSStatusItem when triggered programmatically

Tags: macos, nsstatusitem, nsstatusbar

I have an `NSStatusItem` with an attached menu that I'm triggering with a global hotkey. If I click the menu item I get the highlight as usual, if I use the hotkey the highlight isn't triggered. Does anyone know a way to trigger the highlight?

I've tried overriding the view and drawing it myself in `drawRect` but if there is a nicer way to do it I'd love to hear. Thanks!

The reason I don't want to override the view is then I have to handle icon positioning, clicking to activate the menu, etc.

Comment: [[statusItem button] setHighlighted:true]?

Comment: As far as I can see, the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854217/highlight-nsstatusitem-when-triggered-programmatically#comment40719513_24854217) by @Luke is the correct answer. It should be added as an answer and marked as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

This does the magic in macOS 10.13.6 with Xcode 10.

```
guard let m = statusItem.menu else { return }
statusItem.button?.isHighlighted = true
statusItem.popUpMenu(m)
statusItem.button?.isHighlighted = false
```

Please note that last line is required to de-highlight the icon when the menu gets closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

`[[statusItem button] highlight:true];`

As it turns out `setHighlighted:` and `highlight` don't do the same thing:
[NSStatusBarButton keep highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004684/nsstatusbarbutton-keep-highlighted)